# Send a follow up email in one thread

Tags: microsoft-outlook, outlook-addin

I would like to know if there is a method within Outlook or via an add-in/macro where you can send a follow-up email in one thread/subject.

The reason I'm asking is that we need to separate the "To:" and "From:" sections of all our emails and then copy each individual section into 2 separate parts. All communication to a sender needs to be documented in one part of the document. All communication received from a sender needs to be documented in another. Both need to be documented in the order received.

I.E:

Sent,
Reply,
Sent 1,
Reply 1,

Page 1:

Sent,
Sent 1,

Page 2:

Reply,
Reply 1,

Right now, if a follow-up email does not need to be sent, you can view this information through the "Conversation" view. But if a follow-up email needs to be sent I'm not sure how to keep it in the same "thread". Using the reply key adds the "RE:" prefix. Forwarding adds "FE:" to it. Using the Resend key seems to modify the original email.

Do you guys have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unselect following options via View > Conversation Settings. So you will see received emails in one thread. All your replied ones will be only show in Sent Items folder in one thread.

[image]

Comment: This so far seems to be the best way of doing it. I also found that using the resend option but adding in a horizontal line to indicate that this is a new email, works for Outlook categorizing the email in one 'thread'.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: you are welcome. you can also accept my reply